# Shared hosting provider for Adobe Air Socket servlet?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sockets, air, shared-hosting

I wrote a small Adobe Air server socket app for a small client/server application. Aside from getting a dedicated server, are there any companies out there that would ...
1. Allow running Adobe AIR on the server
2. Grant permissions on ports for socket sending/listening

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not try Amazon Web Services' EC2?

You can grant permissions to whatever ports via [Security Group](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/)s in the administration panel.

Their most basic server - [a micro instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) - is free for a year and even if you want something faster, they are still reasonably priced.

Answer (score 0):

[Rackspace Cloud Severs.](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/cloud-products/cloud-servers/)

You would have Full Root access so you would be able to install anything you like onto the server, and can also grant permissions on the ports.